# Проблема в нахождении наибольшего отрицательного, наименьшего положительного

Tags: c++, массивы

Вообщем, задание, большую часть которого я сделал:
[image: Задание]

Моя проблема заключается в 2 вещах:
1) Как найти наименьшее положительное и наибольшее отрицательное числа.
2) Как найти их позиции (и да, позиции меньшего и максимального чисел я также найти не смог).

Вот мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

    const int rows = 5;
    const int cols = 5;

    int pos = 0;
    int neg = 0;
    int null = 0;

    int iMin = 0;
    int jMin = 0;
    int iMax = 0;
    int jMax = 0;

    double average;
    double sum = 0;

    ifstream matrix("C:\\Это папка\\Матрица.txt", ios::in);

    int arr[rows][cols];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            matrix >> arr[i][j];
            cout << arr[i][j] << " " << "\t";
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;

    matrix.close();

    ofstream final_matrix("C:\\Это папка\\Готовая матрица.txt", ios::out);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            {
                if (arr[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    pos++;
                }
                else if (arr[i][j] < 0)
                {
                    neg++;
                }
                else
                {
                    null++;
                }

                if (arr[i][j] < arr[iMin][jMin])
                {
                    iMin = i;
                    jMin = j;
                }

                if (arr[i][j] > arr[iMax][jMax])
                {
                    iMax = i;
                    jMax = j;
                }



                sum += arr[i][j]; //Для вычисления среднего арифметического

            }
        }
        int prod = rows * cols;

        cout << "Количество положительных чисел в матрице: " << pos << endl;
        final_matrix << "Количество положительных чисел в матрице: " << pos << endl;

        cout << "Количество отрицательных чисел в матрице: " << neg << endl;
        final_matrix << "Количество отрицательных чисел в матрице: " << neg << endl;

        cout << "Количество нулей в матрице: " << null << endl;
        final_matrix << "Количество нулей в матрице: " << null << endl;

        cout << "Минимальное число в матрице: " << arr[iMin][jMin] << endl;
        final_matrix << "Минимальное число в матрице: " << arr[iMin][jMin] << endl;

        cout << "Максимальное число в матрице: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl;
        final_matrix << "Максимальное число в матрице: " << arr[iMax][jMax] << endl;

        cout << "Среднее арифметическое матрицы: " << sum / prod << endl;
        final_matrix << "Среднее арифметическое матрицы: " << sum / (rows * cols) << endl;

        final_matrix.close();

    cin.get();
}
```

Результат работы программы:
[image: Работа программы]

Answer (score 1):

Для минимального положительного:

```
int posCount = 0, minPos = 0, minPosI = 0, minPosJ = 0;    

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
     if (arr[i][j] > 0) {
       if (posCount == 0 || arr[i][j] < minPos) {
         minPos = arr[i][j];
         minPosI = i;
         monPosJ = j;
       }
       posCount++;
    }
  }
}
```

Для максимального отрицательного - аналогично, только наоборот.